# I wanna make the ball to hit opposite side of box

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter,turtle,random,time
from tkinter import *

tk =Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk,width=800,height=600)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_rectangle(10,550,60,600,fill='white',outline='black')
canvas.create_rectangle(740,550,790,600,fill='white',outline='black')
canvas.config(background="light green")

canvas.create_oval(13,553,57,597,fill='blue',outline='black')
canvas.create_oval(743,553,787,597,fill='red',outline='black')

x = 0
y = 0
def SHOT(x,y):
     x += random.random()
     while 35 <= x <= 740:
        y += -(x**x) +35
     return y

while True:
    canvas.move(x,y)
tk.update()
time.sleep(0.05)

tk.mainloop()
```

I am trying to make animation. There are two ball on right and left bottom sides in the boxes and I want to make the ball to heat the other side's box.
It doesn't work... I know what I wrong but I don't know how can I fix it
guys plz help me !!

Comment: y += -(x**x) + 35, this equation is to express parabola, I know this is wrong...

Comment: Explain what exactly is not working. If there is an error, include the full error you are getting in your question.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SeungYoun\Desktop\Game.py..py", line 23, in <module>
    canvas.move(x,y)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2429, in move
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'move') + args)
_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be ".53039280 move tagOrId xAmount yAmount"

Comment: Include this in your question, not in the comments.

Comment: What do you think `while True: canvas.move(x, y)` does? And more importantly, why do you have it?

Comment: I change it to canvas.move(3,x,y)